# stop jwplayer from going fullscreen on browser fullscreen?

Tags: javascript, html, jwplayer, jwplayer6

Let's start with a situation sketch:
I am working on a website that allows the user to enter the Browser's Fullscreen mode, which uses this code:

```
function fullscreen(){
    var body = $("html")[0];
    var requestMethod = body.requestFullScreen || body.webkitRequestFullScreen || body.mozRequestFullScreen || body.msRequestFullScreen;

    if (requestMethod) { // Native full screen.
        requestMethod.call(body);
    } else if (typeof window.ActiveXObject !== "undefined") { // Older IE.
        var wscript = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
        if (wscript !== null) {
            wscript.SendKeys("{F11}");
        }
    }
}
```

For normal usage this works flawlessly, however, when using that piece of code, it automaticcaly triggers the fullscreenmode for a jwplayer (jwplayer6.8) video that is shown somewhere on the page.

I can't get the browser to go fullscreen without opening the video and was wondering if anyone has any information regarding how to solve this as i'm completely clueless.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have an example of where you are running this?

Comment: I copied the parts that affect what I mentioned, since the original source is running in a closed environment at http://publictests.site88.net/jwdemo/

Comment: So, you want the browser to go full screen, but not the player? Wouldn't the full screen api call make every element in the page also go full screen?

Comment: I want the box to be fullscreen to optimize the users experience with no browser toolbars etc, but this triggers the video to start in Fullscreen. All other elements stay the original size

Comment: I can't tell by your example size everything is in full screen though?

Comment: the video, isnt supposed to go to fullscreenmode. I just want the video to stay the original 300x200 box. I added a videotoggle button to hide it, so it might show what it does to other (nonvideo) objects, I just want the browser toolbars etc to dissapear and leave the rest of the page intact, including video.

Comment: I was able to use this plugin from gitub to make only certain elements go full screen, but not the player - https://github.com/sindresorhus/screenfull.js, maybe this will help you with this.

Comment: O interesting, I will definately look into that, thanks for sharing, will update if it worked

Comment: No problem, any time.